# Confusion regarding pole

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Consider the following complex-valued function.
$$f(z)=\frac{\log(z+i)}{1+z^2}$$.
The book which i am referring to states that at $z=-i$, the function has a logarithmic singularity.However , $$\lim_{z\to -i}f(z)=\infty$$ by the L'hospital's rule which suggests that at $z=-i$ , the function  should have a pole. Can someone point out where i am wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $(1+z^2)^{-1}$ part has a pole, the logarithm has its own singularity as well which has a different character.

Comment: Can we say anything on a whole about the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of l’Hospital’s rule is not justified. The denominator $1 + z^2$ does evaluate to $0$ when $z = -i$, but the numerator $\log(z + i)$ doesn’t (undefined). The numerator doesn’t even approach $0$ as $z\to -i$. In fact, its real part approaches $-\infty$ no matter which branch of $\log$ is used.

In any case, the singularity of $\log(z + i)\big/\big(1 + z^2\big)$ at $z = -i$ is not isolated. So, even if this limit is $\infty$, it has no bearing on whether it is a pole, because it’s not an isolated singularity. One requirement in the definition for a *pole* is that it be an isolated singularity.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. I am new to multi-valued function in complex analysis . Could you explain the last line a little in detail . How does real part of $log (z+i)$ goes to $-\infty$ for different branches ?

Comment: @llecxe The real part of $\log z$ is $\log \lvert z\rvert$ no matter which branch, and it approaches $-\infty$ as $z$ approaches $0$. I’ve edited my answer slightly to include why it’s not a pole *even if* the limit did exist.

Comment: Since, near points at $z=-i$ , there are infinite points where $log$ function is not defined , therefore it is not an isolated singularity . Am i correct @shoteyes ?

Comment: @llecxe Yes. That’s precisely why. There is no punctured disk around $z = -i$ for which $\log(z + i)$ is defined and holomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for writing back . Thanks for helping.